# Is this sentence correct: He worked so hard that he may get a pay raise

Tags: grammar

He worked so hard that he may get a pay raise.

Is the sentence correct? Should I use "might" instead of "may" here?

Comment: If the possibility exists at the present time, it's fine to use _may_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence may be read in two different ways.

> He worked so hard [in order] that he might get a pay raise.

If you are trying to imply the purpose he had when working hard, you must use “might” to reflect that was a past purpose.

> He worked so hard that [as a result] he may get a pay raise

If you are trying to imply future possibility, you must use “may.”

It is not correct to assume that only one tense of a modal verb is correct for any meaning. One tense may grammatically imply one idea, and the other tense may grammatically imply a different idea.